# Return rows where specific number is reached for the first time (postgres)

Tags: sql, postgresql, conditional-statements, postgresql-9.5

Have hit a roadblock.

Context: am using PostgreSQL 9.5.8

I have a table, as follows, with customers' points accrued. The table has multiple rows per customer as it records every change in points (like an event table). i.e. customer 1 may buy 1 item and accrue 10 points which is one row, then on another day spend some of these points and be left with 5 points which is another row, and then purchase another item and accrue a further 10 bringing them back up to 15 which displays as another row. Each of these rows with point amounts has a `created_at` column.

Example table:

```
Customer ID  created_at    no_points   row
123          17/09/2017    5           1
123          09/10/2017    8           2
124          10/10/2017    12          3
123          10/10/2017    15          4
125          12/10/2017    12          5
126          17/09/2017    6           6
123          11/10/2017    11          7
123          12/10/2017    9           8
127          17/09/2017    5           9
124          11/10/2017    5           10
125          13/10/2017    5           11
123          13/10/2017    12          12
```

I want to track the first time a customer reaches a certain threshold i.e. >= 10 points. It doesn't matter how much they go over 10 points, the only criteria is that I select the **first** time the customer reaches this threshold. I would also like this query to fetch **only** rows where the customer has reached the threshold of 10 for the first time **in the last week**.

Following these rules, in the above example, I would like my query to select rows 3, 4 and 5.

I have tried the following query:

```
SELECT  x.id,
        min(x.created_at)

FROM (

SELECT 
        p.id as id,
        p.created_at as created_at,
        p.amount as amount 

FROM "points" p 

WHERE p.amount >= 10  )  x 

WHERE x.created_at >= (now()::date - 7)
AND    x.created_at <   now()::date   

GROUP BY x.id
```

I'm unsure that I'm retrieving the right thing however from the result set I am seeing & the results set is huge so it's not evident. Could someone sense check?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use cumulative functions:

```
select p.*
from (select p.*,
             sum(num_points) over (partition by p.customer_id order by p.created_at) as cume_num_points
      from points p
     ) p
where cume_num_points >= 10 and
      (cume_num_points - num_points) < 10;
```

EDIT:

I may have misunderstood the question.  If you just want the first break, one method uses window functions:

```
select p.*
from (select p.*,
             lag(num_points) over (partition by p.customer_id order by p.created_at) as prev_num_points
      from points p
     ) p
where num_points >= 10 and
      prev_num_points < 10;
```

Or, without a subquery:

```
select distinct on (p.customer_id) p.*
from customers p
where num_points >= 10
order by p.customer_id, p.created_at;
```